# Regression Discontinuity Design, staggered treatment allocation

Tags: causality, bias, selection-bias, regression-discontinuity

I'm unsure if this complex allocation rule is appropriate for RDD. I will have data for a staggered rollout treatment where there will be about 10 rounds of selection over two years for services (treatment). We have administrative data that will be updated for each round that we use to rank individuals on "Score 1", flag those above the 99th percentile in a given round as eligible for treatment, then rank the eligible on a different "Score 2" and offer the top 5 people services per selection round. Scores change, and people will join and exit the data between rounds, but once in the treatment group, they are not considered for treatment again.

To build the counterfactual, I would use the 98th to 99th percentile based on each round's data and perform the same steps as those for selection above the 99th that generate the treatment group over the ten rounds. Once allocated to counterfactual, they are not considered for allocation into counterfactual again **but must be moved to treatment if their scores change in future rounds**. The first ranking score and the second ranking score are independent (selected $person_{i}$ in $round_{t}$ appears as-good-as-random along the distribution of Score 1). In a static data simulation, I get a nice continuous running variable for lagged outcomes after 10 simulated selection rounds, generating 50 selected treatment and 50 control, divided by the cutoff. I normalize and pool the cutoffs across selection rounds, as the cutoff should shift slightly on Score 1 across rounds. I will be able to identify the counterfactual cases retrospectively with full information on all measures/statuses for all rounds.

A typical RDD is cross-sectional with contemporaneous allocation. My idea seems unusual but reasonable (thoughts?), but I'm concerned about the staggered allocation. In particular, it's possible/likely that a person in round-1 would be (or would have been) allocated as one of the 10 counterfactual cases for that round. Then, by any $round_{t>1}$ their rank on Score 1 increases over time, and they get "re-allocated" into treatment. This should be few people, so my plan is to exclude all ever-treated from potential counterfactual (retrospectively given I know they later become a treatment case) and define the 98th-99th counterfactual eligibility group each round after excluding those cases that are eventually/ever treated.

Am I generating bias by excluding the people from counterfactual-eligible group who I know will join treatment later (specifically, because their Score 1 is known to increase later). They are effectively replaced with the next-in-line counterfactual person. Any problems with this? Is there a solution?

Comment: I think this will be OK as long as the time of the comparison, the "untreated" outcome is not influenced by the expectation of future treatment or by actual future treatment.

Comment: Thanks @dimitriy, the moment I'm most concerned about is biasing the counterfactual post-values downward by effectively replacing a "known increaser" in Score 1 in the round one allocation group with the next-best-counterfactual person who I have no expectations on. For the model, the rounds are pooled into one multi-cutoff-RDD, but for allocation in calendar time, a few "treated later" will likely be excluded due to future treatment. This type of case would have at least one time-period of increasing in Score 1 while they "should be" in the counterfactual. What do you think?